# Printing a Rotated Leaflet Map and jsPDF

Tags: printing, rotation, leaflet

I am using a Rotate Map Leaflet  plugin and I have the following issue when trying to print with the jsPDF plugin:

The map does not stay within the div container. It covers the entire PDF document. It also seems to do something weird with the map tiles.

This is how it should look:

[image: Div on page]

If I print it with jsPDF, the PDF looks like:

[image: Printed with rotation]

If it is not rotated, it looks like this in the PDF:
[image: printed without rotation]

Not matter what, the map does not stay within the bounds I want it to.

Comment: I found a simple way around this issue:

Answer (score 0):

I used Javascript's localStorage.setItem() function to pass the innerHTML of the div containing the map and other information i wanted to print.

On another page I used Javascript's localStorage.getItem() to retreive the HTML from the previous page and added it to an existing div on this new page.  I also added the css link  and script calls to LeafletR.js.

I used the same code in the previous page to set up the map:

```
map = L.map('map',
{
' renderer': L.canvas(),
'center': [0, 0], 'zoom': 17,
'zoomControl': false,
'rotate': true,
'attributionControl': false,
'maxBounds': [
[25, -125],
[49.5, -66.5]
]
});
```

The map showed up exactly as it should, in the right location, and printed correctly using window.print function.

The window.print() function worked on original page but showed all controls on the page which I didn't want.

Don't know if this is the most eloquent way to get this done but it worked.